# omnet++ INET : generate simple ARP spoof simulation

Tags: omnet++, inet, spoofing

NED file :

```
package arptest;

import inet.networklayer.arp.ipv4.Arp;
import inet.networklayer.common.InterfaceTable;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.contract.INetworkLayer;
import inet.networklayer.contract.INetworkLayerLower;
import inet.networklayer.contract.INetworkLayerUpper;
import inet.networklayer.ipv4.Ipv4RoutingTable;
import inet.node.base.ApplicationLayerNodeBase;
import inet.node.base.NetworkLayerNodeBase;
import inet.node.base.TransportLayerNodeBase;
import inet.node.ethernet.EtherSwitch;
import inet.node.inet.Router;
import inet.node.inet.SensorNode;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import inet.physicallayer.apskradio.packetlevel.ApskScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.transportlayer.tcp_common.TcpSpoof;
import inet.visualizer.contract.IInterfaceTableVisualizer;
import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer;
import inet.visualizer.linklayer.InterfaceTableVisualizer;
import inet.visualizer.scene.NetworkNodeVisualizer;
import ned.DatarateChannel;


network ARPTest
{
    parameters:
        //        @networkNode();
        //        *.interfaceTableModule = default(absPath(".interfaceTable"));
        //        *.client.config.IPv4.ip = "10.0.0.2";
        @display("bgb=874,456");
    //    *.interfaceTableVisualizer.networkNodeVisualizer = default(absPath(".networkNodeVisualizer"));  
    types:
        channel fiberline extends DatarateChannel
        {
            delay = 1us;
            datarate = 512Mbps;
        }
        channel ethline extends DatarateChannel
        {
            delay = 50ns;
            datarate = 100Mbps;
        }

    submodules:
        client: StandardHost {
            @display("p=250,100;i=device/laptop");
        }
        host1: StandardHost {
            @display("p=250,200;i=device/pc");
        }
        host2: StandardHost {
            @display("p=250,300;i=device/pc");
        }
        switch: EtherSwitch {
            @display("p=400,200");
        }
        net: Router {
            @display("p=700,200");
        }
        router: Router {
            @display("p=550,200");
        }
        server: StandardHost {
            @display("p=850,200;i=device/server");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=67,90;is=s");
        }
        visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {
            @display("p=67,142");
        }
        sensor1: SensorNode {
            @display("p=398,350");
        }
        radioMedium: ApskScalarRadioMedium {
            @display("p=67,49");
        }
        MyRouter: MyHost {
            @display("p=443,68");
        }
        standardRouter: StandardHost {
            @display("p=627,350");
        }
    connections:
        client.ethg++ <--> ethline <--> switch.ethg++;
        switch.ethg++ <--> ethline <--> host1.ethg++;
        switch.ethg++ <--> ethline <--> host2.ethg++;
        router.ethg++ <--> ethline <--> MyRouter.ethg++;
        router.pppg++ <--> fiberline <--> net.pppg++;
        server.pppg++ <--> fiberline <--> net.pppg++;
        sensor1.ethg++ <--> ethline <--> switch.ethg++;
        MyRouter.ethg++ <--> ethline <--> switch.ethg++;
        standardRouter.ethg++ <--> ethline <--> router.ethg++;
        standardRouter.ethg++ <--> ethline <--> switch.ethg++;
}
```

The MyHost item is actually replicate fromthe standardHost.

In my scenario, i am intended to simulate a simple ARP spoof. Let say when client host first trigger send message, and ARPREQ will be initiated for the first time. From the NED diagram, there could be 2 possible route, 1 is pass through "MyRouter" and the other is pass through "standardRouter".

From this point, the attacker to be "MyRouter", thus, it should reply a ARPREQ that is send to standardRouter, and therefore spoof the arp by replying the ARPReply by specifying its MAC address that link to the "StandardHost" ip.

However, in my case, i am not able to make the "myrouter" to reponse to the ARPREQ that is send for "standardRouter", which in turn i am failed to generate and arp spoof.

Is there anyway for me to create a simple arp spoof in inet omnetpp ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add NED file of your network?

Comment: NED code added with statement of scenario explained. Hope this help.